# Make Image Pyramid from JP2 Raster

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff, digital-image-processing, image-pyramids, jpeg-2000

I have ~1.7 GB JP2 Buckeye that I want to serve out from Geoserver; I'd like to have it tiled so that the client won't have to redraw everytime they zoom into the map. My current understanding is that the best way to serve this is by building an Image Pyramid out of this so Geoserver can dish it out--however I think the only way to build the pyramid is by using a GeoTiff.

So I have started converting that <2 GB JP2 file (using gdalwarp) and currently I'm at 30% and the file size >13 GB which is HUGE. Plus if I go ahead and build the pyramid out of that file, I feel like the total size of this one file is going to be massive.

Is there a better way that I should serve this data? Ideally I should be using around the same amount of harddrive space as the JP2 but if I'm missing something, I welcome corrections and explanations so I can understand.

**UPDATE**
cmd line used:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs "EPSG:3857" -multi source.jp2 output.tif
```

**UPDATE** per the suggestion of @iant to load up the bugger as a layer (attempted to add it as JP2K (Direct) Coverage Format Raster Data Source), i got the following error:

```
Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: Dimensions (width=111200 height=118200) are too large
```

Comment: can you add your gdal_warp command line? I would use something like
gdal_translate \
  -co COMPRESS=JPEG \
  -co PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR \
  -co TILED=YES \
  5255C.tif 5255C_JPEG_YCBCR.tif

Comment: Are you sure overviews are the best way to go? "JPEG2000 format does not support creation of GDAL overviews since the format is already considered to be optimized for "arbitrary overviews" as per the [gdal docs](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_jp2ecw.html). I'd rather go with a [tile cache](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/webadmin/tilecache/index.html)

Comment: I'd go with a compressed tiled tif with overviews added - see http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2015/02/geotiff-compression-for-dummies.html

Comment: Are you sure GeoServer can't use the JP2K as a layer?

Comment: @iant can't use _translate because i think it loads the file into memory and I don't have that kind of ram on my machine; honestly I didnt think about adding the jp2 as a layer itself, totally forgot about that, will look into this now

Comment: thanks @Kersten, I'll look into the tile cache option if adding the JP2 as a layer fails me

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169395/converting-large-jp2-files-using-gdal for discussion on _translate and jp2

Comment: no dice @iant as loading it as a layer, going to look into tile cache now; also  that last discussion you sent, I get that they're talking about using the appropriate driver for jp2, but I get lost when they mention " --config GDAL_SKIP for skipping the first JP2 drivers".

Comment: I edited my answer, you should not be lost with it any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please, follow iant suggestion about the jpep compressed (big)tiff with jpeg compressed overviews.

I would not go for serving jp2 directly unless you can use kakadu or ecw sdk.
I have not had time to look into the new openjpeg decoder.

**UPDATE**

So based on the comments on the question and the answer, I did the following:

*Reprojecting from jp2 so that wouldn't make massive tif file (38gb from 1.7gb jp2) or take FOREVER*

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3857 -multi -srcnodata 0 -dstnodata 0 -of vrt source.jp2 output.vrt
```

*Make jpeg compressed tif per suggestion*

```
gdal_translate -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR -co TILED=YES output.vrt output.tif
```

*Build image overlays of tif created above*

```
gdaladdo --config COMPRESS_OVERVIEW JPEG --config PHOTOMETRIC_OVERVIEW YCBCR --config INTERLEAVE_OVERVIEW PIXEL -r average -ro output.tif 2 4 8 16
```

Comment: what about gdal_translate for a 4-band jp2, where nodata is stored in the alpha? @simogeo